# How to add methods in a class that uses other classes in UML class diagrams?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, diagrams

I have an index file that uses three main JS classes each defining one method. The JS application is about listing a folder datasets, deleting a dataset from that folder, or uploading a dataset from the same folder. As i defined a class containing one method for each of these functionalities that i use in the Index.js is it correct to leave my Index "class" empty and add the methods in each of the used classes (as made in the class diagram below)?

[image: class diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UML makes a distinction between:

- structural design elements, such as classes and components, ...
- deployable elements such as artifacts (files, executable code, ...), servers, devices.

The [`«manifest»`](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/manifest.html) dependency bridges the two worlds.  It allows to say that an artifact `index.js` file physically embodies some classes or components.

For a useful model, you need to chose what of these two worlds you want to describe:

- If it's primarily about files:  use an artifact for every source file that you include in `index.js`, and keep the `«use»` dependency between those artefacts. If you want for some of these files tell which class they implement,  use a «manifest» between the ("physical") artifact and the ("logical") class.  The artifact is like a black box, the class provides the details of the properties and behaviors that it offers.
- If it's more about classes: see what class or component is implemented in `index.js` and show it in your diagram, but forget about the file. You would then show properties or parts of the imported classes (that you'd somehow instantiate) in this class/components,  or alternatively show associations/compositions with the other classes.  The right modeling would then depend on the content of your source code, so no possibility of more precise explanations here.

Here an example of the first case:

[image]

Comment: it is primarily about files (first case), could you develop an example in that case?

Comment: @SSOF I edited with an example for the first case.  index.js IS the artifact.  For other more specific UML tool questions or UML syntax questions, I'd suggest to go to stackoverflow with UML tag.

Comment: ok, but then how you could add contents of those artefacts, such as the defined methods inside those files?

Comment: @SSSOF  to add a mapping to the content you’ll use the “manifest”. From my own experience, the artifact modelling is not often super-useful. It’s more useful to  focus  on the content: your ide will anyhow quickly locate the file containing a class or a method.  The relationship between the classes takes more reading and is therefore more useful in a diagram for the big picture.